# Does my TRACERT comparing 2 environments show that one env is having issues or is the diff negligible?

Tags: networking

I've noticed much slower app performance when I run a vendor app from my laptop (when I am on-premise) rather than the same app from a VDI.

I'm very much outside of my realm of knowledge and having difficulty finding someone within the company to help me.

Clearly, my PC takes more hops and has slower response times than from a VDI which performs much better.

Do the following differences seem significant enough to blame the network?

**From My PC (poor app experience)**

```
Y:\>tracert MyAppServer

Tracing route to MyAppServer.internal.mycompany.com [10.37.171.225]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  CTAC-A-02B-UA-1A-vl-100.inw.mycompany.com [10.81.194.2]
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  CTAC-A-02D-CA-1B-te2-4.inw.mycompany.com [10.81.128.113]
  3    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  CTAC-A-02D-VE-1A-ge-2-3.inw.mycompany.com [10.81.128.44]
  4    14 ms    13 ms    14 ms  wdc-pwaz-ve-1b-lo0.inw.mycompany.com [10.44.26.5]
  5    14 ms    16 ms    15 ms  wdc-pwaz-1b-eth-2-6.inw.mycompany.com [10.44.24.156]
  6    14 ms    14 ms    14 ms  wdc-sc-2b-po-17.inw.mycompany.com [10.44.24.137]
  7    14 ms    14 ms    16 ms  wdc-ecaz-1a-po-19.inw.mycompany.com [10.40.20.118]
  8    13 ms    17 ms    13 ms  MyAppServer.internal.mycompany.com [10.37.171.225]

Trace complete.
```

**From VDI (Acceptable app experience)**

```
Y:\>tracert MyAppServer

Tracing route to MyAppServer.internal.mycompany.com [10.37.171.225]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  10.38.160.3
  2     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  10.38.0.4
  3     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  MyAppServer.internal.mycompany.com [10.37.171.225]

Trace complete.
```

Comment: Are you in the same location as the VDI server and the application server? Or accessing them via VPN?

Comment: 13ms is an eye-blink & shouldn't be noticeable most of the time in itself. Unless your structure is using a myriad transactions between the two all the time, that shouldn't be the root cause.

Comment: I am not on VPN. I don't know where the VDI that I am connecting to resides.